# I have a trouble when I try to create rule in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.MAMANG 
(
    MASO NVARCHAR(200) NULL UNIQUE,
    NHAMANG NVARCHAR(200)
        CHECK (NHAMANG IN ('Viettel', 'Mobifone', 'Vinaphone',
                           'Vietnamobile', 'Gmobile Beeline')), 
)
GO

CREATE RULE checkPhone AS ((LEN(@typePhone) = 10) OR (LEN(@typePhone) = 11) 
                            AND ISNUMERIC(@typePhone) = 1
                            AND @typePhone = ANY (SELECT MASO FROM TEST.MAMANG)
                          )
GO
```

Comment: Please format your code and clarify your problem, my friend?

Comment: Why not just use a foreign key constraint and a check constraint?

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` on phone numbers is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-rule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on rules is pretty clear:

> **condition_expression**
>
> Is the condition or conditions that define the rule. A rule can be any
>   expression valid in a WHERE clause and can include elements such as
>   arithmetic operators, relational operators, and predicates (for
>   example, IN, LIKE, BETWEEN). **A rule cannot reference columns or other
>   database objects.** Built-in functions that do not reference database
>   objects can be included. User-defined functions cannot be used.

Your rule violates this with:

```
@typePhone = ANY (SELECT MASO FROM TEST.MAMANG)
```

You should just use a foreign key constraint along with a check constraint.

Comment: The documentation also states that that rules should not be used for new development as the feature may be removed from a future SQL Server version.